# Draw this picture using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw this picture using TikZ?
[image]

Comment: Have you made an attempt at all? If you show minimal effort people are usually much more willing to help you completing your goal.

Comment: If you know a bit about `tikz` then this is not hard at all. It can be done in vanilla `tikz` or via `tikz-cd`.

Comment: Please search on the site for `graph` or `commutative diagram` and you will find tons of ressources.

Comment: This question may be closed soon because the problem is not clear. Are you asking about commutative diagrams in general? Or specifically how to circle the nodes in `tikzcd`? Or how to get the double circle around `q_5`? Or how to make the "loop arrows" above `q_1` and `q_2`? Please be specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a `tikz-cd` solution

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\e}{\varepsilon}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5cm, cells={nodes={draw, circle, inner sep=.5mm}}]
|[draw=none]|\arrow[r] & q_0\arrow[r,"{a,\e\to a}"] & q_1\arrow[r,"{\e,\e\to\e}"]\arrow[<-,loop above,"{a,\e\to a}"] 
    & q_2\arrow[r,"{\e,\e\to\e}"]\arrow[<-,loop above,"{b,\e\to\e}"] & q_3\arrow[r,"{c,a\to\e}"] 
    & q_4\arrow[r,"{c,\e\to\e}"] & |[double]|q_5\arrow[ll, bend right,"{\e,\e\to\e}"']
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My compliments for your patience :-) +1

Comment: @Sebastiano, usually I don't answer when OP doesn't make an effort, but I couldn't remember the `|[...]|` syntax for changing the node shape in `tikz-cd`. I figured since I was looking it up anyway I'd give an answer.